# Windows Forms WebBrowser and Google Maps Api Not Displaying Map

Tags: windows, google-maps, webbrowser-control

I am using the .net 4.51 Windows Forms VS 2015. Today all my apps using the WebBrowser control stopped loading Google maps or at least displaying it correctly. The Webbrowser is just blank.

I load the Google maps from:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js? sensor=false">
```

If I zoom in and out quickly on the map the maps appears briefly flickering but wont show. 
Is anyone else experiencing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem to my desktop win32 application and just solved. Maybe you can try my observation, Good luck.
([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098335/only-white-color-with-zoom-control-shown-in-google-maps-div-area))

Answer (score 2):

By adding the following meta tag in a header section solved this issue for me.

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`

Comment: Example plz if possible

Answer (score 0):

This link

http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Versionwill 
sorts the problem but for long term maybe think about using the chrome control for .net

```
CefSharp
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem!!!

In the link, i put the version v=3.21.

```js
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.21&signed_in=false"></script>
```

Comment: Worked for me with the C# web browser. Thanks